# Unable to store MQTT messages into SQL Server (Paho Client) using Python

Tags: sql-server, python-2.7, mqtt, paho

I am attempting to send MQTT messages into SQL Server using Python. To give some background, I am simulating sensor readings, publishing them to a "iot.eclipse.org" and subscribing to them using Paho Client. In the code for subscribing to the messages, as can be seen below, I am calling sensor_handler which uses the message.topic and message.payload as its parameters. However, upon execution, the print messages are printed however, the sensor_handler function is not executed.

I have tried executing sensor_handler separately (using simple sql queries) and seems to be working fine. I think the problem is in on_message() function but I am not exactly sure where and why the problem arises and what to do about it.

```
    import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
    from storeInDatabase import sensor_handler

    broker = "iot.eclipse.org"
    broker_port = 1883

    MQTT_Topic_Room1 = "Building/Room_1"

    def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
        print("Connected with result code "+rc)


    def on_message(client, userdata, message):
       #print("Hallo I have the massage: "+message.payload.decode())
       print "" + message.topic.decode()
       #the following line is not executed but the prints are executed
       sensor_handler(message.topic.decode(), message.payload.decode())
       print "" + message.payload.decode()

    client = mqtt.Client()
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.on_message = on_message

    client.connect(broker, broker_port)
    client.subscribe(MQTT_Topic_Room1)



    client.loop_forever()
    #-----------------------------------------------------------
    #Temp_Humidity_Handler(data) parses json data and stores them in the 
    # sql server table 
    #------------------------------------------------------------
    def sensor_handler(Topic, data):
    if Topic == "Building\Room_1":
            Temp_Humidity_Handler(data)
```

Éxpected output is sensor_handle to exceute and store the messages into the database. The actual output is that only the print statements in the on_message that is printing message.topic and message.payload are printed but sensor_handler is not executed. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: wrap the call to `sensor_hander` in it's own try/expect handler to print out any errors thrown. the `on_message` function is called in it's try/expect block that will hide any error thrown

Comment: @hardillb I just tried adding the try except block inside the on_message. no error is printed. Even when I surround just the sensor_handler with try except, no error is printed. I even tried adding another print statement just below sensor_handler within the try except block, and surprisingly, the print statement is executed and hence the except is never executed.

Comment: ok, but that has ruled out an unknown

Comment: @hardillb Yeahh turns out the same code works with sqlite. I am not sure why there's problem with connecting to SQL Server though